# How to copy all json file to new folder by MsBuild?

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

Steps to reproduce
On windows it works fine with this command :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <PreBuildEvent>IF NOT EXIST "$(TargetDir)DataFiles" MKDIR "$(TargetDir)DataFiles"</PreBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>FOR /R "$(SolutionDir)\Api.Tests\Scenarios" %25%25f IN (*.json) DO COPY "%25%25f" "$(TargetDir)DataFiles\" /Y</PostBuildEvent>

  </PropertyGroup>
```

On linux , I have this kind of error

```
Build FAILED.
[12:44:39][Step 1/1] 
[12:44:39][Step 1/1] /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.302/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1331,5): error MSB3073: The command "IF NOT EXIST "DataFiles" MKDIR "DataFiles"" exited with code 127. [/opt/jetbrains/buildAgent/work/4fc9032bf5656724/Api.Tests/Api.Tests/Api.Tests.csproj]
[12:44:39][Step 1/1]     0 Warning(s)
[12:44:39][Step 1/1]     1 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post build event uses `CMD.EXE` specific code - also known as (Windows) BATCH commands. In other words it is platform specific.

Best thing is to use MSBuild built-in features to copy files:

- Remove the PreBuildEvent and PostBuildEvents properties
- Add the following inside the "Project" tag of your project file (best at the end).

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
     <BuildDependsOn>
     $(BuildDependsOn);_CopyAuxFiles
     </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="_CopyAuxFiles">
      <MakeDir Directories="$(TargetDir)DataFiles"/>
      <ItemGroup>
         <Files Include="$(SolutionDir)\Api.Tests\Scenarios\*.json"/>
      </ItemGroup>
      <CopyFile SourceFiles="@(Files)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)DataFiles"/>
  </Target>
  ```

You might need to replace "$(TargetDir)" with "$(OutputPath)".

Comment: I post the answer, but I want to know the best, can you look and say what of them the better?

Comment: I'd say they are equivalent. Yours is also considering sub directories, which I didn't care about, but given a closer look your question's original version would have done so. So yours is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by

```
    <Target Name="CopyScenarios" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>  
      <Scenarios Include="$(ProjectDir)/Scenarios/**/*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Scenarios)" DestinationFiles="@(Scenarios->'$(TargetDir)DataFiles/%(Filename)%(Extension)')" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
  </Target>
```